# The best way to distribute Java files

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, packaging

I hava a Java project that relies on several libraries, which are distributed as JAR files. When I build my project, I end up with `myProject.jar` with a `lib` folder that contains a JAR file for each of the libraries I used.

To distribute my project, I suppose I could just zip up the entire `dist` folder, but that's not very clean.

Rather than making a separate executable for each platform (`.app` for Mac, `.exe` for Windows, ...) that contains the libraries, is there a way to make a single cross-platform file (preferably a JAR) that I can distribute?

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with just zipping up the entire dist folder either. Or use some sort of cross-platform installer like InstallAnywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many tools that pack up a bunch of JARs into one. Enrique's suggestion is a higher-level tool for distributing applications; a lower-level more direct tool to do exactly what you ask is [JarJar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/).

Answer (score 5):

You can consider using [Java Web Start](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/).

Basically, you create a configuration file and put it up on a web site, along with whatever JARs you need.  In that configuration file, you can specify what it needs to download.  After downloading everything, it puts an icon on the user's desktop for them to launch your program.

You can also configure it to automatically download updated JARs whenever necessary.

Comment: Have datestamps or similar in the filenames so their name change when the code change.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [IzPack](http://izpack.org/)